# Aesop Tactic in Lean

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib

Simple question, but can someone explain the role of the aesop tactic in general, and as it pertains to SimpleGraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SimpleGraph`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Combinatorics/SimpleGraph/Basic.html#SimpleGraph) is a definition of a "simple graph" in the mathlib4 library. The API for `SimpleGraph` uses [`aesop`](https://github.com/JLimperg/aesop) to help automate some common proof steps.

I'm guessing from your question that you've noticed the command

```
/--
A variant of the `aesop` tactic for use in the graph library. Changes relative
to standard `aesop`:

- We use the `SimpleGraph` rule set in addition to the default rule sets.
- We instruct Aesop's `intro` rule to unfold with `default` transparency.
- We instruct Aesop to fail if it can't fully solve the goal. This allows us to
  use `aesop_graph` for auto-params.
-/
macro (name := aesop_graph) "aesop_graph" c:Aesop.tactic_clause*: tactic =>
  `(tactic|
    aesop $c*
      (options := { introsTransparency? := some .default, terminal := true })
      (rule_sets [$(Lean.mkIdent `SimpleGraph):ident]))
```

This sets up a custom wrapper around `aesop` that uses some additional rules suitable for working for `SimpleGraph`.

It's not clear from your question whether you've read the README for `aesop` yet. Perhaps you could do so and then clarify your question if needed?

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and see the README for aesop. I'm not familiar with writing such wrappers, so I guess I was just a bit lost.